# QML: show only certain Components depending on a State

Tags: qt, qml

I have several `ui.qml` files, let's say `A.ui.qml`, `B.ui.qml`, `C.ui.qml`.

Then I have to create, depending on a `State`, a window that shows A+B, or B+A, or B+C, etc.

In my `main.qml`, I've actually written the following:

```
...
Item {
    id: contentArea
    state: "state1"

    AForm {
        id: aForm
    }

    BForm {
        id: bForm
    }

    states: [
        State {
            name: "state1"
            PropertyChanges { target: aForm; x: 0 }
            PropertyChanges { target: bForm; x: 400 }
        },
        State {
            name: "state2"
            PropertyChanges { target: aForm; x: 400 }
            PropertyChanges { target: bForm; x: 0 }
        }            
    ]
...
```

So, when setting `contentArea.state = "state2"`, A and B forms are swapped.

But this is just an example to see if it works.

Now I need to create all the forms (I guess using `Component`) and show them only if the state is a certain one.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You replace `AForm` and `BForm` by `Loader`s, and set the `source`-property of this `Loader`s to the right file name, or the `sourceComponent` to the right `Component id`.

```
Loader {
    id: topLoader
}
Loader {
    id: bottomLoader
    y: 200
}

states: [
    State {
        name: "state1"
        PropertyChanges { target: topLoader; source: "AForm.ui.qml" }
        PropertyChanges { target: bottomLoader; source: "BForm.ui.qml" }
    },
    ...
]
```

This process will destroy and recreate the instances of the `ui.qml`-files whenever the state changes.

You can also use e.g. a `ListView` with `snapMode: ListView.SnapToItem`, `interactive: false`, and change the `currentItem` when the state changes.

You could also create all the objects, and only parent the two you want to show to `Item`s that serve as *frames*, and the rest is parented to `null`.

Or you use three or four `Loader`s of which you only show two, that you shift around as necessary, only loading files that shall be shown. Here you will need to write a bit more logic.